# Deployment on IoT device remotely from VS 2015 failed with unexpected error: 'Wrong format: Unrecognized date-time format

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

Deployment of Windows IoT background application from my Visual studio on remote IoT (Raspberry pi 3) device is failing.
Error from the output log of visual studio does not provide any insight into the actual issue.

Error which I am getting in Visual Studio - 
**Error : DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'Wrong format: Unrecognized date-time format.'.**

Here are my device setup details:

1. visual studio 2015 on my Hyper-V virtual Windows 10 machine.
2. Remote device - Raspberry Pi3 running Windows 10. (10.0.14393.67)
3. Created IoT background application using the template (without any
   code changes).

It is building successfully but while deployment it is throwing an error -

How to fix this deployment related error?

Thanks,
/vikas

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce your issue. Could you make sure you're using VS2015 with update 3, and have 14393 SDK installed?

Comment: I tried with below combination with same set of error -
1. VS2015 + Update 1
2. VS2015 + Update 3

Comment: Interesting error! Is your developer machine in a different language or region to the target device?

Comment: I checked both the system. Raspberry Pi3 and my development machine both are in PST timezone with en-US culture. It might be the case that error content is masking some other critical error related to deployment from Visual studio. Just to highlight one more thing, I can deploy sample app from Windows IoT dashboard directly to remote RPi3.

Comment: Actually I am able to resolve this issue by installing Windows 10 SDK version 10.1.10586.212. Although this SDK version is not the latest, but still it is allowing me to deploy the application on Remote IoT device. I had the earlier version of 10.1.10586.15 already installed but somehow the latest version of 10586 has resolved the issue.

Comment: And I hate all the mysterious behaviors, like this~